# What should we do with all this stage 2 baby food now that my son is eating stage 3?

Tags: infant, food, babyfood

My son recently started eating Stage 3 baby food - and this is great!

But, now I have a whole lot of Stage 2 food left over, and I'm not sure what to do with it all.

Should we continue to feed him some Stage 2 food in addition to his Stage 3 meals?  Or should we completely stop feeding him Stage 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There’s nothing nutritionally wrong with stage 2 baby food; it’s fine to use it up. It’s just that it’s not as interesting as stage three and doesn’t accustom the baby to more “real/solid” foods. But nutritionally, it’s like you eating soup instead of steak. It’s all good.

Feel free to use it as is, or if you really want to keep pushing the envelope, incorporate it into more solid food: the puréed fruit and veggies can be incorporated into baked goods, deserts, etc. Your imagination is the only limitation.

Of course there are always women’s shelters and food banks that would welcome baby food. Totally up to you.

Comment: What about mixing some of it into the second half of a stage 3 food jar to try and rehydrate it a little bit?

Comment: @Zibbobz - Sounds fine to me!

Comment: As a side note, it may vary by area, but a lot of charities won't take anything that's been opened or is past the expiration date. If you are a member of a "giving page" or parenting group, they're often less picky. Worse comes to worse, much to my wife's chagrin, I use my kid's old food (and food they decide they don't want to eat) that we can't give away as impromptu snack food. :-D

Comment: @SeanDuggan I would never try to donate opened or expired food. Not sure I’d ever want it, either.

Comment: I'd throw out expired food for my own baby - so I definitely wouldn't give it to anyone else's.  ...Snacking though maybe, depending on which ones.